# Azure CDN Rules Engine: rule to redirect for first time only - Angular Static WebApp Fallback routing

Tags: angular, azure, angular-routing, azure-cdn

I have an Angular app that is hosted on Azure. My routing was not working properly and I got one solution for it which is not feasible but it works.
For example, I want my user to login into the account before starting using Bank Application. For that, when user hit URL MyBank.com/Login it should use internal Angular routing and should show login button like this
[login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZBrn.jpg)

But When I host on Azure it gives me a 404 error due to the fact that Azure tries to determine the route first before passing the request to your site which means anything other than the root URL will fail.

The quick and dirty way to get around this is to set the error document path to be index.html which means when Azure fails to find the route it will direct the request to the index.html document which will render the route client side. The downside of this approach is that the browser will also report a 404 error, but at least the requested page will render. [azure hack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwdRn.jpg)
This hack works fine but it is not a proper solution.

**Now comes the question:**
The proper way to do this type of fallback routing is through **Azure CDN's Rules Engine** but right now I'm unable to figure out the rules and condition to by which I only want my URL to redirect only if the Requested URL dosent Exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings, it will work.
You could try adding in the values, all your root paths, including the /login or any /auth path from redirection, if applies.

There might be another wildcard to use, like "begins with /", but i'm not having good results with that yet, perhaps a broad wildcard works for you.

[image]